# Obtaining the complement of dictionary

Tags: python, string, dictionary, nlp

I have a dictionary letters

```
letterstoProbabilityMap={"aaa":0.4,"bbb":0.7,"ccc":01}
```

for which I have three letter strings and their probability of occurring(I have shortened the dictionary).
I am assigning these probabilities based on some training data. But I also want to assign a probability to strings/keys I haven't seen. e.g "aaa".
Since all my keys are within the set aaa-zzz.
Is there a quick way for me to obtain the non assigned/complement and assign a value quickly. (I understand my question is quite abstract.)

**EDIT**
The value is not fixed it is actually a la place probability.
Below is a code snippet I use to compute the probabilities I do know
The point is I reserve a probability mass which I will then assign to the three letter strings I haven't seen(because I know all strings are between aaa-zzz)

```
for trigram in sorted(threeletter_counts.keys()):
        numerator=threeletter_counts[trigram]+1 
        denominator=twoletter_counts[trigram[:2]]+30
        prob=numerator/denominator
```

Comment: So have you got 26*26*26 keys? aaa to zzz?

Comment: BTW 0.4+0.7+... is greater than 1.0

Comment: Not quite I have a relatively random amount of keys between aaa-zzz I want to got through the dictionary find out the ones that I don't have which are in the set aaa-zzz and assign a value. I am basically doing some laplace smoothing for the values I don't have in my training data

Comment: Is the default value the same for all missing keys? Or even always zero?

Comment: Not quite I figured it relies on the weight I have given the strings I have seen. So I have a  la place value I calculate for the elements I have seen in the training data and I shift the probability accordingly

Comment: try googling `language model`.

Comment: I am implementing a language model manually so I can try to understand.  I am aware that toolkits exist but I think its better to attempt these things to gain a stronger understanding

Answer (score 3):

You could go through all strings and use `setdefault`:

```
for letters in itertools.product(string.ascii_lowercase, repeat=3):
    letterstoProbabilityMap.setdefault(''.join(letters),
                                       computeMissingProbability(letters))
```

Though if the calculation is expensive and would go to waste often because most keys already exist, better check first:

```
for letters in itertools.product(string.ascii_lowercase, repeat=3):
    key = ''.join(letters)
    if key not in letterstoProbabilityMap:
        letterstoProbabilityMap[key] = computeMissingProbability(letters)
```

Or maybe use a `defaultdict`, if that works for you:

```
fullMap = collections.defaultdict(lambda: 0.123, letterstoProbabilityMap)
```

If the default value is just 0.0:

```
fullMap = collections.defaultdict(float, letterstoProbabilityMap)
```

Comment: But I would guess this would only work with a fixed value ?

Comment: `defaultdict` is just for fixed value, yes. With the `setdefault`, you could compute a value based on the letters, though if that is expensive and most keys already exist, then you'd better first check whether the key exists and then assign like normal if it doesn't.

Comment: Nice just out of interest would they be a way of adding non lettered characters ?

Comment: You mean like digits and punctuation? Just add them, like `string.ascii_lowercase + '0123+-*/'` (of course if it's more than a few special ones, there might be better ways than listing them explicityly like that).